High Humidity in one of the two bathrooms
We live in Portland, OR (read moist winters but fairly dry summers). It is peak summer right now, amid a heat wave with 100F high. We have Indoor Humidity ~48-50%. Outdoor humidity ~30%
We have two bathrooms, used for a comparable amount of time in the morning. Around an hour after showering with the exhaust on, BathA has 2-3% more humidity than indoor humidity (say 52%). BathB has around 60% and does not change even after hours of exhaust fan use. BathB is smaller, closer to the HVAC, and maintains temperature better, so it is counter-intuitive.
I have seen this only in the last few weeks, and it coincides with the weather warming up. I assume that the exhaust in BathB is not as effective. It was fine until the weather was cool so hot steam would go up anyway, but not as much now.
A recent history is worth mentioning. Until six months back, BathB's vent was dangling inside the attic and disconnected from a Roof Vent. This led to mold creation in the attic and caused me health issues. We got the vent fixed and mold remediated, and I am so much better now. But my health has been triggered for the past two weeks, which makes me suspect BathB's high humidity.
Questions

What else could be causing higher humidity in BathB?
Could mold be growing somewhere around the fan inside the attic?

Appreciate all the inputs.

Is the roof vent working properly or is it blocked? Are you getting good airflow out of the roof vent? If it is too dangerous to get on the roof to verify outflow, can you verify that the exhaust fan is pulling air out as well in B as in A? Is there an a/c vent inside the bathrooms or do you depend on conditioned air getting in through the open bathroom door? Do you leave the bathroom doors open after showering or shut them?

How are you measuring humidity? The difference between 52% in A and 60% in B doesn't seem to me to be large eouugh to worry about.  We have a 3-bdrm 2-bath tract house built 1970, but there are (small) hvac vents in the bathrooms and exhaust fans which vent directly into the (well ventilated) attic. Been tht way for 54 years and I have never seen any mold in the attic I will sometimes turn on the airhandler fan  to ON before one of us showers to pump conditioned air into the bathroom

a colder room will register a higher relative humidity for the same specific humidity (actual amt of water in the air).  Could also be as simple as the vent not working well for any number of reasons.
